# Secure spreadsheet evaluation using JavaScript. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, json, security, eval, spreadsheet

I was thinking about creating spreadsheets using JSON and JavaScript. This is actually rather a theoretical question about JavaScript.

In some cases, it would be a lot more useful, when you could generate a whole column using a single function. Like in this example:

```
{
    "type": "jsheet",
    "version": "1",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "title": "Example Spreadsheet",
    "groups":
    [
        {
            "name": "Document Information",
            "columns":
            [
                {
                    "name": "Title",
                    "rows": [
                        "_.title"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Author",
                    "rows": [
                        "_.author"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "name": "Numbers 1-10",
            "columns":
            [
                {
                    "name": "Even numbers",
                    "rows": "_.range(1,10).evens()"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Odd numbers",
                    "rows": "_.range(1,10).odds()"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This seems perfectly ok, when you work only with code from trusted source and only on your computer. But think about a cloud service like Google Drive. If users paste insecure code or open insecure spreadsheets, they can run into danger. For example, a script could manipulate the DOM, even could get access to cookies, perform requests and so on. Is there a way to securely prevent this from happening, without implementing a custom JavaScript parser?

EDIT on Kenneth's answer:
Of course I'm not planning to use `eval()` to parse the document itself. I'm only thinking about using `eval()`, or functions defined in the document to evaluate expressions. Think about the possibility of specifying a whole column using this single line of script: `_.range(1,10).evens()` or `_.range(10,200).filter(isprime)`. Where `_` is an object which has methods that return another objects, which have similar methods. Like the chain in jQuery and d3.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `JSON.parse`, there is no problem.

Of course, if you use `eval()` then everything is possible.

Comment: Of course I was not intending to use `eval()` to parse any JSON. I was only thinking about using `eval()` or functions to evaluate expressions. Check my edit on the question.

Comment: Well, what it basically boils down to is: you can't use eval on any non-trusted source. So if you really want to allow certain expressions but not others, you'd need to do a sanitation.

Comment: Someone told me once, that Facebook and some other websites have their own complex solution to create a sandbox for integrated apps. Which actually parse and filter code. I never worked on any Facebook App, but I think something like this could be a solution. Is this the way you mean the sanitation?

Comment: I don't know about Facebook and others, but yeah, basically some sanitation has to be done

Comment: Well, I think this way of solution can be implemented using a finite-state automaton parser, but I think it still doesn't worth implementing this until I need it for really complex spreadsheets. It would take weeks or months for me to implement a spreadsheet engine like this. But I upvoted your answer as it leaded to a  useful consequence. I'm still waiting for an answer that has a simple solution.